# I need to have "profile url" functionality in my jsf application, is there any way apart from filters I can achieve this?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I need to have "profile url" functionality in my jsf application, is there any way apart from filters I can achieve this?

For ex: 
www.website.com/dan.thomas should take me to the Dan Thomas`s page

I can not use filter to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not use filter to achieve this.

Then it stops here. There are no other ways. You might consider to reformulate the question to solve the concrete problem why you cannot use filters for this, at least, if it's actually a programming problem.

Comment: "No Filter" because each incoming request has to pass through that extra filter. I was trying to use <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> to examine each request in the filter with the help of regex, this will add to extra processing and delayed response. If filter is the only way then can you think any other implementation? Thanks

Comment: It'll likely be the regex which makes it slow, not the filter. That's almost a no-op.